# How do I get a java swing combobox to display a column from an array instead of what it is displaying?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, combobox

I am using the following code to populate a combobox:

```
private void fillComboBox(ArrayList<Customer> a){
        filling = true;
        for (Customer c : a)
            selectCustomerCB.addItem(c);
        filling = false;
    }
```

The values for the array are stored in a plain text file (customers.txt).  There are three values for each customer, email, first name, and last name.  I would like for the combobox to display the email address for each customer, but it is displaying "jamesdevenberg.customer.Customer@xxxxxxx" where xxxxxxx are alpha-numeric characters that are different for each customer, and change every time I run the application.

How do I get the combobox to display the email address instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually adding a `Customer` reference instead of an email. I don't know how does the `Customer` class look like, but:

```
selectCustomerCB.addItem(c.getEmail());
```

would be more appropriate.
The `getEmail()` method would be a member of the `Customer` class that returns an email retrieved from a file.

**EDIT:**
The other approach is to override `toString()` method in the `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer {
    String email;

    /*... implementation ... */

    public String toString(){
        return email;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and though it does fix the problem, it creates a whole host of other problems.  Once I do that, the rest of the app doesn't work, starts throwing all kinds of exceptions, and won't display any information.

Comment: Please, add the `Client` class implementation. Otherwise I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding a Custom object to the combo box then you need to create a custom renderer for the combo box to display the email property of the Custom object.

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and examples on how to do this.